# Why I can't join partial tables into one in Sqlite3?

Tags: database, database-design, sqlite

[image]

I decomposed a large table into five tables based on BCNF and I tried to join them all together to check if I lost something or not.

I used this sql statement in **Sqlite3**

```
Select
    spart.Sno, spart.Sname, 
    cpart.Cno, CtoT.Cname,
    CtoT.Tno,tpart.Tname,
    scorepart.Degree

from spart, cpart, CtoT, tpart, scorepart

where
    cpart.Cname = CtoT.Cname
    spart.Sno = scorepart.Sno
    CtoT.Tno = tpart.Tno
    cpart.Cno = scorepart.Cno;
```

And I got `Error: near "spart": syntax error`

Could anybody help me out?

Comment: You need to add `AND` in between each term of your `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select
    spart.Sno, spart.Sname, 
    cpart.Cno, CtoT.Cname,
    CtoT.Tno,tpart.Tname,
    scorepart.Degree

from spart, cpart, CtoT, tpart, scorepart

where
    (cpart.Cname = CtoT.Cname)
    and (spart.Sno = scorepart.Sno)
    and (CtoT.Tno = tpart.Tno)
    and (cpart.Cno = scorepart.Cno);
```

I'm not sure the parentheses are really needed.  I've forgotten the syntax rules.